# OSM Layer in Bing maps

Tags: bing-maps, openstreetmap

Since Bing Maps last update I can't find OpenStreetMaps layer. Is OSM unsupported by Microsoft in Bing Maps for now?

Comment: Note that integrating OSM layers with Bing Maps is against the terms of use for Bing Maps as noted here: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html

Answer (score 0):

This is possible - here is a blog post that provides some of the details:

http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/04/01/displaying-open-street-map-and-esri-tiles-on-bing-maps-ajax-v7/

The quick pointer is to create a custom tile source representing OpenStreetMaps and add it as a tile layer into the map.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a Windows Store App solution (WinRT), check the following link
[Bing Maps OSM sample](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bingmapswindows8/thread/c280e7ed-578b-454e-8e0e-d4b8656c59b3)